# graphical theme settings: a nested list structure with easy access to all levels?

Tags: r

[I'm reinventing the wheel (*), and the question of its shape springs to mind.]

For a [graphical display of a table](https://github.com/baptiste/tablegrob), I want to propose a theme that provides easy access to all aesthetic customisations (e.g. fill background for the cells, colour of the text, font size, etc.).

[image]

A list is the obvious choice. However, the complication comes from the fact that the table has an intrinsic structure too; it can have a column header, a row header, as well as the core entries. Each of these three blocks should have its own specific aesthetic defaults and requirements, but with a common parent to inherit from. Indeed, I want to be able to specify directly that all the fonts should be black, and unless I specifically overwrite the column header, it will inherit this color too.

One possible construct is the existing framework of function environments (closures) in R: the nested structure is automatically resolved when arguments are evaluated. This is my example:

```
# helping function
inplace <- function(l, ...) modifyList(l, list(...))

table_theme <- function(bg = c("grey95", "grey98"),
                        fg = c("black", "black"),
                        just=c("center","center"), hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5,
                        padding = unit(c(4,4),"mm"), 
                        font = list(family = "sans", size = 12, face = "plain"),
                        separator = list(h=FALSE, v=TRUE), box = FALSE,
                        core = list(bg=bg, fg=fg, parse=TRUE,
                                    separator=separator, box=box, padding=padding,
                                    just=just, hjust=hjust, vjust=vjust, font=font),
                        col_header = inplace(core, parse=FALSE, 
                                             font=inplace(font, face="bold")),
                        row_header = inplace(col_header, just=c("right", "center"),
                                             font = inplace(font, face="italic"),
                                             hjust=1, padding=unit(c(4,4),"mm"))){

  list(bg=bg, fg=fg, 
       font=font, separator=separator, box=box,
       core=core, row_header=row_header, col_header=col_header)
}

theme = table_theme()
```

It works (surprisingly!) well, but there's one problem still: if I want to change only one default attribute of the children, I lose all the other default values. For instance, in the above `theme`, it is not trivial to modify `theme$col_header$font` during the construction: I have to rewrite the full call as

```
table_theme(col_header = inplace(list(bg = c("grey95", "grey98"),
                            fg = c("black", "black"),
                            just=c("center","center"), hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5,
                            padding = unit(c(4,4),"mm"), 
                            font = list(family = "sans", size = 12, face = "plain"),
                            separator = list(h=FALSE, v=TRUE), box = FALSE), 
             font=inplace(font, face="bold"))
```

It is however relatively easy to modify after the theme is created,

```
theme$col_header$font$face <- "bold"
```

Am I missing a smart way to use the best of both worlds -- automatic self-consistent evaluation of the nested structure using the closure and easy access to individual traits of the children?

PS:
(*): I'm aware that ggplot2 has a new theming system featuring some inheritance; unfortunately it is tightly bound to the internal rendering system and naming system of ggplot2, so rather unusable for other graphical elements.

Comment: I think this question will end up having a bounty on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than reinvent the wheel, I'd probably take inspiration from the **lattice** package's parameter setting utility functions.  To modify individual leaves of **lattice**'s tree of graphical parameters (as returned by `trellis.par.get()`), `trellis.par.set()`), it allows you to pass in list structures containing values of just those elements you want to change.

Instead of going on about it, I'll just show you what that idea might look like applied to your problem:

```
library(grid)
inplace <- function(l, ...) modifyList(l, list(...))
table_theme <-
    function(...,
             bg = c("grey95", "grey98"),
             fg = c("black", "black"),
             just=c("center","center"), hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5,
             padding = unit(c(4,4),"mm"),
             font = list(family = "sans", size = 12, face = "plain"),
             separator = list(h=FALSE, v=TRUE), box = FALSE,
             core = list(bg=bg, fg=fg, parse=TRUE,
             separator=separator, box=box, padding=padding,
             just=just, hjust=hjust, vjust=vjust, font=font),
             col_header = inplace(core, parse=FALSE,
             font=inplace(font, face="bold")),
             row_header = inplace(col_header, just=c("right", "center"),
             font = inplace(font, face="italic"),
             hjust=1, padding=unit(c(4,4),"mm"))){
        ll <- list(bg=bg, fg=fg,
                   font=font, separator=separator, box=box,
                   core=core, row_header=row_header, col_header=col_header)
        dots <- list(...)
        Reduce(modifyList, c(list(ll), dots))
    }
## Two ways to change both the size and face of the col_header font

## (1) Pass in both modifications in a single list 
theme1 = table_theme(list(col_header=list(font=list(size=10, face="italic"))))
## (2) Pass each modification in in a list of its own
theme2 = table_theme(list(col_header=list(font=list(face="italic"))),
                    list(col_header=list(font=list(size=10))))
## Check that they both have the same effect
identical(theme1, theme1)
# [1] TRUE
```

Although passing in `list(col_header=list(font=list(face="italic")))` is a bit more verbose than doing `col_header$font$face <- "italic"`, the structures are completely homologous, so the former shouldn't be too hard to get the hang of.

Comment: clever use of modifyList with Reduce, I like it. Yet somehow, this `list(list(list(` has something unappealing. I wonder, starting from a end-user perspective, what would be the most natural way to refer to these elements, yet compatible with the parser? Maybe something like `table_theme() & .(col_header$font$face, "italic")`

Comment: @baptiste I hear you. The `list(list(list` thing is ugly and awkward and uncomfortable, and  I've never liked having to use it with lattice. All it has going for is that it *does* work in a predictable way. (That, and it allows for really easy storage and use of personalized themes.) I like your suggested alternative, except it seems like *it* becomes ungainly if you want to change several leaves out at a single branch tip. Then would you have to do `.(col_header$font$face, "italic") & .(col_header$font$col, "red") & .(col_header$font$family, 2)` and so on? Interesting question, though!

Comment: I had in mind that the right-hand side could be a list, eg `.(col_header$font, list(face = "italic", family = 2))`, but obviously there will be a point where the "list of lists" syntax burden has moved to the other side!

Comment: @baptiste Exactly. The optimal solution will probably depend on how many parameters users will typically be changing in each call to the function. I feel like the following goes about halfway towards making the `list(list(list` solution more tolerable: `. <- list; .(col_header=.(font=.(face="italic")))`. A better print method for these lists -- one which only printed `$col_header$font$face` and not also `col_header` and `col_header$font` --- would get another quarter of the way there. This discussion has at least made me appreciate why Deepayan did things the way he did with **lattice**!

Comment: yes; I have often had the problem when explaining lattice options to new users, that it felt unnecessarily verbose, but I always thought: however else would you do it?